# Cannot insert HTML content even removing kses filters

Tags: wp-insert-post

I am creating post using the following code, but I cannot make the HTML content go through, they are being stripped automatically..

```
$post_data = [
  "post_title" => $question,
  "post_content" => $content,
  "post_type" => "bw-faq",
  "post_status" => "publish"
];
kses_remove_filters(); // Disable the kses filters so that HTML  content can pass through
$faq_post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);
kses_init_filters(); // Enable back the kses filters
```

I am fighting for long time, but cannot solve it out.. Can someone please help?

Comment: `wp_kses()` doesn’t run when programmatically inserting a post. Are you certain that the HTML is being stripped on input, and not on output? How are you verifying this? Do you have an example of HTML that is stripped.

Comment: Hi @JacobPeattie I was reading the WP Docs, and it seems insert_post goes through sanitization. I was checking this by editing the post in wp back end and I noticed that the anchor tags were not there. So this is definitely not output.. When I added <a> tag in kses allowed tags, it worked. So definitely WP is removing the tags during insert_post()

Comment: Ah, you're right, my mistake. However, as far as I can tell, this shouldn't happen if the user is an administrator, and `a` tags are allowed regardless. It seems like you have a theme or plugin that is filtering the post content on its own. Have you tried disabling all plugins? Do you have any of your own code that filters post content in any way?

Comment: Hi Jacob, I am writing a plugin myself to create posts by reading data from a CSV. But anyways, for now I am done with allowing A tag in kses.. Thanks for the help though.